# passing value from one form to another using code behind files in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to check to see if the value of `UserAuthInfo.Current` is set when redirecting from the `default.aspx` page to the `profile.aspx` page. Below is the code I have on both pages:

DEFAULT.ASPX code snippet

```
if ((logonHolder.AccountStatus))
{

  UserAuthInfo authInfo = new UserAuthInfo();
  authInfo.UserID = logonHolder.UserID.ToString();
  //strlogon_ID
  authInfo.IsAuthenticated = true;                                
  authInfo.Attributes.Add("logon_ID", logonHolder.UserID);
  authInfo.Attributes.Add("Email", txtEmail.Text);
  authInfo.Attributes.Add("UserType", logonHolder.UserType);
   if (logonHolder.UserType == "A")
   {
     authInfo.Attributes.Add("IsAdmin", "Y");
   }
   else
   {
     authInfo.Attributes.Add("IsAdmin", "N");
   }
   authInfo.Roles.Add(logonHolder.UserType);
   authInfo.Attributes.Add("LastName", logonHolder.LastName);
   authInfo.Attributes.Add("FirstName", logonHolder.FirstName);
   authInfo.Attributes.Add("user_employee_number", logonHolder.EmployeeID);
   authInfo.Attributes.Add("user_id", logonHolder.UserID);
   authInfo.Attributes.Add("SessionGUID", _holderService.CreateSession(strret_code, logonHolder.UserID));

   authInfo.CreateTicket(); 
   Session["Session"] = "Valid";
   authInfo.Attributes.Add("user_login_security", LoginSecurity.Unrestricted);

**if (UserAuthInfo.Current != null && UserAuthInfo.Current.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    Response.Redirect("profile.aspx", false);
  }**
```

Profile.aspx Page_Load code snippet

```
if (UserAuthInfo.Current == null || !HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl, true);
  return;
}
```

When running the code, the value of UserAuthInfo.Current is set on the default.aspx page, but it is always null on the profile.aspx page.

Comment: You can send your object from one page to another page using session, query string or public properties of the page

Comment: In which line do you set UserAuthInfo.Current? I cannot see it...

Comment: @OlafWatteroth the op is setting the instance of the variable here ` UserAuthInfo authInfo = new UserAuthInfo();`  the problem is in the if statement should be checking `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(authInfo)){ }` not the object itself
this line needs to use the `authInfo` variable if (UserAuthInfo.Current != null && UserAuthInfo.Current.IsAuthenticated)

Comment: The line in the default.aspx page with the "If" is there to perform a check only. that line is not staying. However, at that point UserAuthInfo.Current is getting set. Once I redirect from default.aspx to profile.aspx and try to validate that the value is still set, it is reverted back to null...so the value is not getting saved as I move from one form to the next. I do have ViewStateMode set to Enabled on the default.aspx form.

Comment: @MethodMan: Creating a local instance does not set the (probably) static variable `UserAuthInfo.Current`.

@GRACIASCIENTE: So the property GET creates an instance? But why do you set all the settings and data to a local instance of UserAuthInfo?

Answer (score -1):

Then use a global class accessible for all pages, Below is the code I have on both pages:

```
public class MyGlobal
{
static string _variable;
public static string Variable
{
        get
        {
            return _variable;
        }
        set
        {
            _variable= value;
        }
}
```

and use it so:

```
MyGlobal.Variable = UserAuthInfo.Curren;


string current = MyGlobal.Variable ;
```